# Exclude id column for associations

Tags: sql-server, sequelize.js

I have an association in Sequelize ORM set as:
`process.belongsTo(binary, {foreignKey: 'binary_id'});` between `process` and `binary` models. I query the `process` model using the code:

```
process.findAndCountAll({
    include: [{
        model: binary,
        attributes: ["name", "version", "company"]
    }],
    attributes: ["id", "command"],
}).then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

The SQL query generated by this is:

```
SELECT 
  [process].[id], 
  [process].[command], 
  [binary].[id] AS [binary.id], 
  [binary].[name] AS [binary.name], 
  [binary].[version] AS [binary.version], 
  [binary].[company] AS [binary.company] 
FROM [process] AS [process] LEFT OUTER JOIN [binary] AS [binary] ON 
     [process].[binary_id] = [binary].[id];
```

As you can see, it includes one extra column, `binary.id` even thought I have not mentioned in the `attributes: []`.

I also tried adding `through` parameter as mentioned [here](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3664),

```
process.findAndCountAll({
    include: [{
        model: binary,
        attributes: ["name", "version", "company"],
        through: {
            attributes: []
        }
    }],
    attributes: ["id", "command"],
}).then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

But I get the following error with this:

> Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTableName' of undefined

So, is there a way I can prevent it from being added? Or exclude the `id` column of the `binary` model?
I am working with MSSQL.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
process.findAndCountAll({
    include: [{
        model: binary,
        attributes: ["name", "version", "company"],
        through: {
        attributes: []
        }
    }],
    attributes: ["id", "command"],
}).then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

[Source](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3664)

Comment: If I add the `through` parameter, it throws the error: `Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTableName' of undefined`